# Short story: ultimate Martian weapon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mars

I am trying to remember the name of a book of short stories. It was a very thin paperback, with only 4 or 5 stories, and the cover was predominantly black. I don’t remember if it had any image on it. It was probably published in the 1970s, or possibly the early 80s.

The story I remember best was the first in the collection. It was set in the near future, in which space travel exists, and Mars is being settled from Earth. It is a bleak hostile world, which used to be ruled by a technologically advanced civilisation that mysteriously vanished, leaving various artifacts behind. This would be consistent with the book being from the 70s, as there are no “Martian canals”, but nonetheless conditions are not as harsh as we now know they are.

In any case, the story deals with a pair of Earthman treasure hunters who come across an ancient cache of military equipment in a cavern. They first find small arms (but of extreme power), then larger weapons, including something like a laser cannon which had a protective forcefield. Clearly Earth technology had not yet advanced to creating forcefields. Then they found a squad of robot warriors, and finally an unusual helmet. When one of the men puts it on, he realises he can hear his colleague’s thoughts “…yes, with these weapons and this army we can knock over a third world country, then live in luxury for the rest of our lives…” When he hears this, he calmly shoots the man, and remarks “No ambition. With this equipment, I could rule the world.”

He sees one last box in the cavern marked something like “The final weapon” in the Martian script. He opens it, and a grey amorphous shape floats out. At first, thinking it was poison gas he runs from it, but the shape condenses around the man’s corpse on the floor and remarks “Still protoplasm. I like still protoplasm.” It then consumes the body in a gulp.

It drifts after the remaining man who opens fire on it with the Martian guns to no effect. He operates the forcefield, but the shape just drifts through it. “Live protoplasm. I like live protoplasm” it remarks, and consumes him. It then goes to the surface looking for the many units of live protoplasm, “just as there had been so many centuries ago”.

I would really love to know who the author was. Even fifteen years later I can still remember some of the dialogue verbatim  (well… I think I can), so it made a big impression on me. The other stories were less memorable. One was about a man with a very elaborate model train set up, who finds himself shrunk to the scale of the model, and is eventually killed by the trains.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The story you remember is [The Last Weapon](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58564) by Robert Sheckley.

> The thing kept coming.
>
> “Die, die!” Parke screamed, his nerves breaking.
>
> But the thing came on, grinning broadly.
>
> “I like quiet protoplasm,” the thing said as its gigantic mouth converged on Parke.
>
> “But I also like lively protoplasm.”
>
> It gulped once, then drifted out the other side of the field, looking anxiously around for the millions of units of protoplasm, as there had been in the old days

I would guess the anthology is [Far Out](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?13230) as the length matches. The cover is mostly but not completely black:

[image: Far Out]

I cannot find a copy of Far Out, but the last story in the anthology is [The Attic Express](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?94970), and this is obvious railway related as it is also collected in [Macabre Railway Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?485561) so it seems a good candidate for the train story you recall.

Comment: Thank you John. Yes, "The Attic Express" is the story about the model railway disaster, and "Far Out" is indeed the collection. It was published in 1974, so my date estimate was pretty good!